# skipping incompatible

Tags: compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux, make, c, libpng

I want to compile C files using make with the libpng library. However, this is what I got after typing the "make"

```
 make
gcc mp5.o main.o -o mp5 -lpng -g -m32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so when searching for -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a when searching for -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so when searching for -lpng
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:14: mp5] Error 1
```

It seems that the issue is because I'm trying to run the library on a 32 bit machine. But, I don't know if there's any workaround. Should I just work on a 64 bit machine at this point?

Edit: I just realized that the machine that I'm currently working on is actually 64 bit. I just put the -m32 option there because I initially thought I was working in a 32 one. But removing it doesn't solve the problem though

I'm using WSL in Windows 11

Comment: It looks like you *are* working on a 64 bit machine, but are trying to build for a 32 bit target (`-m32`) - please clarify exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: got it just editted my comment

Comment: @steeldriver yeah, i initially thought i was working on a 32 bit machine turns out not. removing it doesn't seem to solve the problem though

Comment: Did you clean the directory (i.e. delete the `.o` files) after removing the erroneous `-m32` option? If not, `make` will consider them to be up to date and won't replace them.